# integrating pentaho reporting with java

Tags: java, pentaho

I am using pentaho report designer to generate reports.My datasource is mondrian olap cube.Now , I want to integrate my reports with java. I downloaded pentaho reporting sdk and modified the existing sample java program and provided the path of my .prpt file.But I am getting following error:

```
    org.pentaho.reporting.libraries.resourceloader.ResourceCreationException: Unable to parse the document: ResourceKey{schema=org.pentaho.reporting.libraries.docbundle.bundleloader.ZipResourceBundleLoader, identifier=content.xml, factoryParameters={org.pentaho.reporting.libraries.resourceloader.FactoryParameterKey{name=repository}=org.pentaho.reporting.libraries.repository.zipreader.ZipReadRepository@ef028b, org.pentaho.reporting.libraries.resourceloader.FactoryParameterKey{name=repository-loader}=org.pentaho.reporting.libraries.docbundle.bundleloader.ZipResourceBundleLoader@19007a5}, parent=ResourceKey{schema=org.pentaho.reporting.libraries.resourceloader.loader.URLResourceLoader, identifier=file:/C:/Users/devang/workspace/samples/eclipse-bin/org/pentaho/reporting/engine/classic/samples/anor_admin.prpt, factoryParameters={}, parent=null}}
    at org.pentaho.reporting.libraries.xmlns.parser.AbstractXmlResourceFactory.create(AbstractXmlResourceFactory.java:249)
    at org.pentaho.reporting.libraries.resourceloader.DefaultResourceManagerBackend.create(DefaultResourceManagerBackend.java:272)
    at org.pentaho.reporting.libraries.resourceloader.ResourceManager.create(ResourceManager.java:411)
    at org.pentaho.reporting.libraries.resourceloader.ResourceManager.create(ResourceManager.java:370)
    at org.pentaho.reporting.libraries.resourceloader.ResourceManager.createDirectly(ResourceManager.java:207)
    at org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.samples.Sample1.getReportDefinition(Sample1.java:70)
    at org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.samples.AbstractReportGenerator.generateReport(AbstractReportGenerator.java:160)
    at org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.samples.AbstractReportGenerator.generateReport(AbstractReportGenerator.java:128)
    at org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.samples.Sample1.main(Sample1.java:132)
ParentException: 
org.pentaho.reporting.libraries.xmlns.parser.ParseException: Failure while loading data: datadefinition.xml [Location: Line=5 Column=11] 
    at org.pentaho.reporting.libraries.xmlns.parser.AbstractXmlReadHandler.performExternalParsing(AbstractXmlReadHandler.java:337)
    at org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.modules.parser.bundle.content.ContentRootElementHandler.parseDataDefinition(ContentRootElementHandler.java:290)
    at org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.modules.parser.bundle.content.ContentRootElementHandler.parseLocalFiles(ContentRootElementHandler.java:242)
    at org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.modules.parser.bundle.content.ContentRootElementHandler.doneParsing(ContentRootElementHandler.java:236)
    at org.pentaho.reporting.libraries.xmlns.parser.AbstractXmlReadHandler.endElement(AbstractXmlReadHandler.java:163)
    at org.pentaho.reporting.libraries.xmlns.parser.RootXmlReadHandler.endElement(RootXmlReadHandler.java:586)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.endElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanEndElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.pentaho.reporting.libraries.xmlns.parser.AbstractXmlResourceFactory.create(AbstractXmlResourceFactory.java:236)
    at org.pentaho.reporting.libraries.resourceloader.DefaultResourceManagerBackend.create(DefaultResourceManagerBackend.java:272)
    at org.pentaho.reporting.libraries.resourceloader.ResourceManager.create(ResourceManager.java:411)
    at org.pentaho.reporting.libraries.resourceloader.ResourceManager.create(ResourceManager.java:370)
    at org.pentaho.reporting.libraries.resourceloader.ResourceManager.createDirectly(ResourceManager.java:207)
    at org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.samples.Sample1.getReportDefinition(Sample1.java:70)
    at org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.samples.AbstractReportGenerator.generateReport(AbstractReportGenerator.java:160)
    at org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.samples.AbstractReportGenerator.generateReport(AbstractReportGenerator.java:128)
    at org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.samples.Sample1.main(Sample1.java:132)
```

My program is:

```
/*
 * This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify it under the
 * terms of the GNU Lesser General Public License, version 2.1 as published by the Free Software
 * Foundation.
 *
 * You should have received a copy of the GNU Lesser General Public License along with this
 * program; if not, you can obtain a copy at http://www.gnu.org/licenses/old-licenses/lgpl-2.1.html
 * or from the Free Software Foundation, Inc.,
 * 51 Franklin Street, Fifth Floor, Boston, MA 02110-1301 USA.
 *
 * This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful, but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY;
 * without even the implied warranty of MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
 * See the GNU Lesser General Public License for more details.
 *
 * Copyright (c) 2009 Pentaho Corporation..  All rights reserved.
 */

package org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.samples;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;

import org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.DataFactory;
import org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.MasterReport;
import org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.ReportProcessingException;
import org.pentaho.reporting.libraries.resourceloader.Resource;
import org.pentaho.reporting.libraries.resourceloader.ResourceException;
import org.pentaho.reporting.libraries.resourceloader.ResourceManager;

/**
 * Generates a report in the following scenario:
 * <ol>
 * <li>The report definition file is a .prpt file which will be loaded and parsed
 * <li>The data factory is a simple JDBC data factory using HSQLDB
 * <li>There are no runtime report parameters used
 * </ol>
 */
public class Sample1 extends AbstractReportGenerator
{
  /**
   * Default constructor for this sample report generator
   */
  public Sample1()
  {
  }

  /**
   * Returns the report definition which will be used to generate the report. In this case, the report will be
   * loaded and parsed from a file contained in this package.
   *
   * @return the loaded and parsed report definition to be used in report generation.
   */

  public MasterReport getReportDefinition()
  {

    try
    {
      // Using the classloader, get the URL to the reportDefinition file

      final ClassLoader classloader = this.getClass().getClassLoader();
      final URL reportDefinitionURL = classloader.getResource("org/pentaho/reporting/engine/classic/samples/anor_admin.prpt");

      // Parse the report file
      final ResourceManager resourceManager = new ResourceManager();
      resourceManager.registerDefaults();
      final Resource directly = resourceManager.createDirectly(reportDefinitionURL, MasterReport.class);
      return (MasterReport) directly.getResource();
    }
    catch (ResourceException e)
    {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
  }

  /**
   * Returns the data factory which will be used to generate the data used during report generation. In this example,
   * we will return null since the data factory has been defined in the report definition.
   *
   * @return the data factory used with the report generator
   */
  public DataFactory getDataFactory()
  {
    return null;
  }

  /**
   * Returns the set of runtime report parameters. This sample report uses the following three parameters:
   * <ul>
   * <li><b>Report Title</b> - The title text on the top of the report</li>
   * <li><b>Customer Names</b> - an array of customer names to show in the report</li>
   * <li><b>Col Headers BG Color</b> - the background color for the column headers</li>
   * </ul>
   *
   * @return <code>null</code> indicating the report generator does not use any report parameters
   */
  public Map<String, Object> getReportParameters()
  {
    final Map<String, Object> parameters = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    parameters.put("stday", 28);
    parameters.put("styear", 2012);
    parameters.put("stmonth", 10);
    parameters.put("eday", 10);
    parameters.put("eyear", 2012);
    parameters.put("emonth", 10);
    return parameters;
  }

  /**
   * Simple command line application that will generate a PDF version of the report. In this report,
   * the report definition has already been created with the Pentaho Report Designer application and
   * it located in the same package as this class. The data query is located in that report definition
   * as well, and there are a few report-modifying parameters that will be passed to the engine at runtime.
   * <p/>
   * The output of this report will be a PDF file located in the current directory and will be named
   * <code>SimpleReportGeneratorExample.pdf</code>. 
   *
   * @param args none
   * @throws IOException indicates an error writing to the filesystem
   * @throws ReportProcessingException indicates an error generating the report
   */
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ReportProcessingException
  {
    // Create an output filename
    final File outputFilename = new File(Sample1.class.getSimpleName() + ".pdf");

    // Generate the report
    new Sample1().generateReport(AbstractReportGenerator.OutputType.PDF, outputFilename);

    // Output the location of the file
    System.err.println("Generated the report [" + outputFilename.getAbsolutePath() + "]");
  }
}
```

Comment: Check in more detail the cause and parent properties of the exception, there should be more details about other exceptions, since there can be many causes. What do you see in those properties?

Comment: Devang Did you find a solution for this?